Streamlit (python) and sessions - how do I get the session variable from another python file
I am using streamlit and I call a function in a separate function file from a login script, the function.py queries SQL and loads a bunch of data in the st.session as follows:
st.session_state["company_id"] = company_id

Once the user has logged in , I want to reference that st.session_state["company_id"] from the rest of my application in all the other .py files, I have tried to output st.session_state["company_id"] and all I get is:

KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "company_id".Did you forget to initialize it?

Edit:
So I have a login screen where I set the session state to "logged in":
  if st.button("Login"):
        # Check login credentials
        # st.write(checklogin(username, password))
        
        if checklogin(username, password):
            st.success("Login successful! Redirecting to the Dashboard...")
            st.session_state["logged_in"] = True
            redirect_js = """<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=dashboard"> """
            st.markdown(redirect_js, unsafe_allow_html=True)

When it opens the redirect Dashboard screen, the session_state does not exist and gives the 'KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "logged_in". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization' message.
If I pass the same session variable from another test page and then go to the Dashboard, it works fine.

You should create a sample code where you can show the error.
